Why is normalization calculated like this?
I'm reading a research paper, in which the researchers mentioned that all data is normalized to zero mean unit variance. For this particular model, the normalization stats are calculated while the model is training.
While the model is training, the normalization function accumulates stats for a million steps and then uses those stats for normalization.
The normalization function looks like this (pseudo code):
normalized_data = (data - mean) / std_with_epsilon()

This makes sense to me. However what doesn't make sense is the std_with_epsilon() function.
Instead of calculating standard deviation as one would expect from math literature, the std_with_epsilon() function calculates it like this:
During the accumulate phase, it sums all of the input data squared:
accumulated_sum_squared += data**2

then, when std_with_epsilon() is called, it calculates std like so:
std = squareRoot(accumulated_sum_squared / safe_count - mean**2)
return max(std, 1e-8)

This isn't what I would expect the standard deviation calculation to be.
Can someone explain what's going on here? Or point me towards any resources that would help explain?
Here's a link to the actual source code.

what did you expect? this looks like $E[x^2]-E[x]^2$ equation to me

Check out the preceding line in the code, return (batched_data - self._mean()) / self._std_with_epsilon().   The max(std, 1e-8) is a kluge to avoid a possible division by zero when self is a vector of constant values.  It appears to assume the magnitudes of values in self will be greatly larger than 1e-8.

This transformation is usually called "standardization", not "normalization"

I expected a standard deviation calculation, e.g. squareroot( 1/n * sum(data - mean)**2).   It looks like the calculation that confused me earlier is actually the variance, which is the standard deviation squared. Thanks!
